# In Spring-WS, while using WS-SecurityPolicy, how do I specify strict layout?

Tags: spring-ws, ws-security, wss4j

I am trying to consume a web-service exposed by Websphere with WS-SecurityPolicy and strict layout. SOAP generated by Spring-WS client fails against due to layout ordering.

The exact error is this (I am using time-stamp, with encryption and signing) :

```
Signature for timestamp found ahead of timestamp. Strict Layout not followed in incoming message.
```

I am using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor. But I could not find a WSS4J property to enforce a strict layout.

Update : I found a similar query raised in Spring forum [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/71910-ws-security-xwss-and-timestamp-position-in-soap-header). There is no response to that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Web-service (latest release uses WSS4J 1.6.5) doesn't expose any property for changing the layout. I had to add an interceptor to programmatically move around time-stamp node in the soap message after the WSS4J call in Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to upgrade to a more recent version of WSS4J. See:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-424

Colm.

Comment: Latest Spring-WS uses WSS4J 1.6.5. Unfortunately the fix version WSS4J 1.6.10 fails on direct drop, with some other error. I am extending Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to move around the nodes. If that works, I'll add the solution.